# Failed to parse XML with an optional element with serde-xml-rs

Tags: xml, rust, serde

I have a tree of serde-annotated structs and it succeeds in parsing the sample XML, including this fragment:

```xml
<bmsg>
    <cmsg>
         <!-- ... -->
    <cmsg>
<bmsg>
```

Now I am testing with a large sample XML file and the following structs fail because sometimes `<cmsg>..</cmsg>` is missing. I was deserializing this using:

```
#[derive(Serialize,Deserialize, Debug)]
struct A {  
    #[serde(rename="bmsg")]
    messages: B,                 // <====
}

#[derive(Serialize,Deserialize, Debug)]
struct B {  // bmsg
    #[serde(rename="cmsg")]
    list: Vec<C>,
}
```

Which resulted in an error in the second struct:

```
panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: missing field `cmsg`
```

I changed the first struct to have a `Vec<>` so it can deal with an optional element:

```
#[derive(Serialize,Deserialize, Debug)]
struct A {  
    #[serde(rename="bmsg")]
    messages: Vec<B>,            // <====
}

#[derive(Serialize,Deserialize, Debug)]
struct B {  // bmsg
    #[serde(rename="cmsg")]
    list: Vec<C>,
}
```

But serde continues to give the same error. I tried `Option<>` too, but didn't get anywhere.

What baffles me the most is that I use `Vec<>` all over the place and never ran into this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would appear `Option<T>` means that the item *does exist*, it just is void of content.

[The documentation seems to suggest using](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#serdedefault) the `default` attribute, to tell the deserializer to use the implementation of the [`Default` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) for the type *if it cannot be found*.

With that in mind, perhaps this would work for you:

```
#[derive(Serialize,Deserialize, Debug)]
struct A {  
    #[serde(rename = "bmsg")]
    messages: B,
}

#[derive(Serialize,Deserialize, Debug)]
struct B {  // bmsg
    #[serde(rename = "cmsg", default)] // <----- use default to call `Default::default()` against this vector
    list: Vec<C>,
}
```

You can find [the code I used to check this in the Playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=3780a988aa21c7a6525bea438af0f2fd&version=stable). It won't run in the Playground, but it produces your expected results running locally.

Comment: This is a correct and very well elaborated answer. Note I tried #[serde(default)], but only on the first struct :/  Thank you!